# shell script to find lines between special character and a string

Tags: python, shell

I have a txt file (Network switch configuration file) there is multiple interface with the name of GigabitEthernet1 GigabitEthernet1/1 GigabitEthernet1/2 and so on and ohter interface as wel, they are separated by ! this symbol. I want to grep all these interface in another file whose name is Gigabit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJzGj.gif)

As shown in image 
i juse want all GigabitEthernet interface only in another file.

Comment: in Python you should be able to split by ! and then get only strings containing GigabitEthernet. Also note that the text example of your input string is a lot more useful than a picture.

Comment: Your question is unclear - please try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the Record Separator to an exclamation mark, `awk` will read each *"paragraph"* of your file surrounded by exclamation marks as a single record.

Then just have to find records that contain `Gigabit Ethernet` like this:

```
awk '/interface GigabitEthernet/' RS='!' YourFile
```

I only typed your datafile in approximately since you posted a picture of your data - which is not very helpful :-)

**Sample Output**

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description something A
 switchport access vlan22
 switchport mode access


interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 description something B
 switchport access vlan98
 switchport mode access


interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 description something A
 switchport access vlan22
 switchport mode access
```

---

If you want the output in a new file, do this:

```
awk '/interface GigabitEthernet/' RS='!' YourFile > NewFile
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got exactly what i want. can you help me to check how can i check that, description entry is exist or not in each interface.

Comment: Should be possible. What should it do if present? If not present?